# Laravel generate a unique ID using Storage::put

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel `Storage::putFile()` when I store uploaded files and I like the convenience of it's automatic unique file name and how it takes care of file extension.

Now I want to get a file from a remote server (`file_get_contents($url)`) and store it like I did for uploaded files, but I don't find any equal method in the docs.

In https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files in the `put` method, you have to specify the file name.

Comment: Well you can always do an `md5($url)` to generate a filename for that URL

Comment: I am also surprised I have to generate my filename by hand when creating it from content.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$filename = uniqid(). '.' .File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());
//uniqid() is php function to generate uniqid but you can use time() etc.

$path = "Files/Images/"
Storage::disk('local')->put($path.$filename,file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: finally `file_get_contents` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you have an `UploadedFile` instance you can also use `$file->hashName()`

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_hashName

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#L52

Comment: I'm not uploading a file. it's a download from another server

Answer (score 2):

If anynone is looking for the default Laravel unique filename generator, behind the scenes Laravel uses `Str::random(40)` to generate a unique filename when you're uploading a new file.

Here is the method `store` used on `UploadedFile` instance when you store a new file:

```php
namespace Illuminate\Http;

/**
 * Store the uploaded file on a filesystem disk.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  array|string  $options
 * @return string|false
 */
public function store($path, $options = [])
{
    return $this->storeAs($path, $this->hashName(), $this->parseOptions($options));
}
```

The `hashName()` method came from the Trait `FileHelpers.php`

```
namespace Illuminate\Http;

/**
 * Get a filename for the file.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $path
 * @return string
 */
public function hashName($path = null)
{
    if ($path) {
        $path = rtrim($path, '/').'/';
    }

    $hash = $this->hashName ?: $this->hashName = Str::random(40);

    if ($extension = $this->guessExtension()) {
        $extension = '.'.$extension;
    }

    return $path.$hash.$extension;
}
```

So if you follow the same logic as Laravel you can basically use `Str::random(40)` Laravel's helper to generate a unique filename, for more uniqueness you can append the current datetime to the string.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure the filename is unique and to get the extension of your file url, you can do like this :

```
$ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);    
$filename = bcrypt($url).time().'.'.$ext;
```

Comment: bcrypt also uses `/` so this is a really bad idea on a Linux environment